# MySQL wildcard matching any character or none

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

I have a query using MATCH similar to :

```
..
MATCH product_title, product_d1, product_d2, product_d3 AGAINST ('+VALUE*')
..
```

Where VALUE is a keyword modified by PHP and it refers to a keyword which a product title could contain or any of the other fields.

The problem appears when I want to use a search like "pens", as I would like to recognise those which are "pen" in singular. This problem is not that easy to solve as if I remove the ending "s" it doesn't recognise keywords like "christmas" which is a singular word.

Is there any wildcard to specify "any character (1 length)" or "none" ? Otherwise I guess I should create 2 lines specifying the plural or singular but that would take a longer execution time.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Juan, how is that link related to this question?

Comment: It's an example, SQL injections are prevented on the original query.

Comment: The problem is much easier if the match keyword is the singular version

Answer (score 0):

Have a singular to plural mapping table. To keep the size of this table down, you can just put exceptional words such as 'christmas' in there.

You can index both the singular and plural columns for mapping from one to the other.